# Return the text of only one <h3> parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, mobile

ok so i'm creating a mobile app using jquery mobile and i have a dynamically created button that is created when the user searches for a contact. when the user finds a match for his/her searched contact the name is displayed in a dynamically created  tag. the results can return duplicates if more than one person of the same name exists. with the code i have now if i click the button i just want it to alert me the name contained in the  above the button. it works fine unless there's duplicates then it alerts all of the names because all of the buttons have the same class.

here is the loop that creates the  and the buttons:

```
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
            $('#srchResults').append("<div id='resultdiv"+i+"' data-role='collapsible'><h3 id = 'nameh3"+i+"'>"+contacts[i].name.formatted+"</h3>"+"<p>"+'<a href="#"                  data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="btnDisguise">'+'Plus'+'</a>'+'<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="btnInfo">'+'Info'+'</a>'+"</p></div>").trigger('create');    
    }
```

and here is the .btnInfo function upon a click:

```
    $(document.body).on('click', '.btnInfo', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    h3text = $this.parents().find("h3").text();
    alert(h3text);
    });
```

i need to find a way to just alert the  the button is associated with, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: typo? `var $this = $(this),` should end with `;`

Comment: @DrixsonOseña: Might have been a typo, but it is not ungrammatical (although in this case indentation is usually different, with `h3text` indented under `$this`).

Comment: @DrixsonOseña How is that a typo? They're declaring two variables...`$this` and `h3text`

Comment: @DrixsonOseña that would  make `h3text` a global variable which I'm sure is not what OP wants

Comment: @charlietfl, no I didn't mean that just pointing a syntax error it's an comment btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class attribute to the `resultdiv` then use `.closest()` to find the `resultdiv` to which the clicked button belongs to then the `h3` inside it

```
 for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
     $('#srchResults').append("<div id='resultdiv" + i + "' class='resultdiv' data-role='collapsible'><h3 id = 'nameh3" + i + "'>" + contacts[i].name.formatted + "</h3>" + "<p>" + '<a href="#"                  data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="btnDisguise">' + 'Plus' + '</a>' + '<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="btnInfo">' + 'Info' + '</a>' + "</p></div>").trigger('create');
 }
```

then

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.btnInfo', function () {
     var $this = $(this),
         h3text = $this.closest('.resultdiv').find("h3").text();
     alert(h3text);
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PS8ku/)